# Passing Values Between Views in Django

Tags: python, django

Simple scenario - firstview has a form (firstform) which has a field 'reference'.  In secondview, there is a separate form (secondform) which also has a field 'reference'.  I would like to initialize the value of 'reference' in secondview to be = the value of 'reference' in firstview.

Am I able to do this without passing that parameter through the URL?

I am using python 2.7 for reference.

This is what I've tried.  It doesn't seem to work this way and I am getting a "does not exist" error which I know just mean that I'm not actually getting that value.

views.py

```
def firstview(request):  

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = FirstForm(request.POST) #this form contains 'reference'
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('secondview')


def secondview(request):
    form = SecondForm(request.POST)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

            ...



    reference_id =  request.POST.get('reference') #this is how Im trying to get reference from the firstview

    form = SecondForm(initial={

         'reference': Orders.objects.get(reference=reference_id), #this is where im getting "does not exist" error

         })
   ....

    return render(request, 'manifest_readonly.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Activate [django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/) and then you can pass data between views using request.session dictionary as follows:

```
def firstview(request):
    ...
    form = FirstForm(request.POST) #this form contains 'reference'
    ...
    request.session['selected_form'] = form
    ...

def secondview(request):
    ...
    form = request.session.get('selected_form')
    # now use the form data here
    ...
```

Comment: what is ```selected_form``` here? does this pass all the data in the form or just an individual field?

Comment: It is just a variable named selected_form, you can pass whatever you want using this.

Comment: How will the applicable `url` look like?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't want to pass it in the URL, but if not you can use the session.

```
def firstview(request):  
    ...
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        request.session["reference"] = form.cleaned_data["reference"]
        return redirect('secondview')

def secondview(request):
    ...
    reference_id =  request.session.pop('reference')
```